# Use grunt-browser-sync to watch changes in jsp and tag files

Tags: jsp, gruntjs, tags, grunt-browser-sync

I'm trying to use the grunt-browser-sync to watch the changes in the jsp and tag files, but the same is not working. Does anybody know what`s happening?
Grunt works with tag and jsp files?

```
 module.exports = function(grunt) {    
   // Project configuration.
   grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        watch: {   
           // hide code
        },   
        less: {
           // hide code
        },  
        // hide code
        browserSync: {
            default_options: {
                bsFiles: {
                    src: ["**/*.js", "*/*.css", "**/*.jsp", "**/*.tag" ]
                },
                options: {
                    watchTask: true,
                    proxy: "https://pageteste.local:9001/sitedeteste"
                }
            }
        }   
    });

    // Plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-browser-sync");

    // Browser sync task
    grunt.registerTask("server", ["browserSync", "watch"]);

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'sprite', 'sync']);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need change my code path for this:

```
bsFiles: {
    src: [
        "web/path/**/*.js", 
        "web/path/css/style.css",
        "web/**/*.jsp", 
        "web/webroot/path/**/*.tag", 
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your globbing pattern is wrong use:

```
         bsFiles: {
                src: ["**/*.js", "*/*.css", "**/*.jsp", "**/*.tag" ]
            },
```

Comment: I update my code with this change, but it still works only .js files. 

`browserSync: { 
default_options: { 
bsFiles: { 
src: ["**/*.js", "*/*.css", "**/*.jsp", "**/*.tag" ] 
}, 
options: { 
watchTask: true, 
proxy: "https://pageteste.local:9001/sitedeteste" 
} 
} 
}`